# Delete all files from a folder using a bat that match a certain pattern in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I want to delete all files in a folder that start with a certain string (for example `"File_EXC"`) and that are `.zip` files.

How can I do this with a batch file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `CD` to the correct path.
2. `DEL FILE_EXC*.ZIP`
3. Press Enter

Answer (score 1):

Would it be satisfactory to have it run at shutdown, instead of taking up process cycles by looping every 10 minutes?   If so:

> Open a Command Prompt, type `gpedit.msc` and click OK. 
>   Expand Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | select Scripts (Startup/Shutdown) .
>   Double-click Shutdown in the right side pane.
>   Click Add, and put your batch file's filename and path in there.
>   Test it by shutting down and restarting, then looking for the files which should have been deleted.

If not, create a second batch file here named LOOPY.BAT which contains:

```
REM LOOPY.BAT
:loop
command /c batchfilename.bat
timeout /t timeToWaitBetweenCallsInSeconds /nobreak
goto :loop
```

Comment: This answer doesn't describe how to delete files matching a certain pattern. And the question doesn't mention anything about running in a loop or at shutdown.

Comment: I've asked the OP to modify the question, as he posted another question which dovetails into the first, but what was rejected for lack of clarity.